# Parsing the output of sqlite PRAGMA information into a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pragma

I am trying to use the SQLite command to gather information on column names:

```
columnsQuery = ("PRAGMA table_info(%s)" % (table))
columnNames = cursor.execute(columnsQuery)
```

Per the research i've done, executing this command should give me the column names within a given table. Because of the fact that I do not have a sqlite database readily available, I am unaware of what the output of PRAGMA looks like. Is there a way that I can parse my variable "columnNames" to be a Python list of column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of a pragma has columns and rows, just like a query:

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.18.0 2017-02-11 14:59:58
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> create table t(id integer primary key, name text not null, date default current_date);
sqlite> .mode columns
sqlite> .header on 
sqlite> pragma table_info(t);            
cid         name        type        notnull     dflt_value  pk        
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           id          integer     0                       1         
1           name        text        1                       0         
2           date                    0           current_da  0
```

Comment: And this means that once you have a Cursor object, you can get the values of the `name` column with `[row[1] for row in cursor]`.

Comment: so without even executing a PRAGMA statment, I can just use [row[1] for row in cursor]? @dan04

Comment: You'd get the cursor from executing something.

Answer (score 1):

The query result is a list of tuples with 4 value as follow:
[(0, 'id', 'INTEGER', 1, None, 1), ... ,]

the following code can print all column names:

```
columnsQuery = cursor.execute(f"pragma table_info('{table[0]}')")
columnInfos = cursor.fetchall()
columnNames = [item[1] for item in columnInfos]
```